# how to show color box in filter of listing page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I want to show different color box in place of color name under shop by filter in listing page.
Now it is showing color name but i want to show color box there.I searched for free extension but i didn't get any extension to show color box under shop by filter of listing page.

I am also unable to create in pages so if anyone have any idea to do in pages or any free extension then please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If an extension is a valid answer for you, then you can use this one: http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus.
Among other cool stuff regarding the layered navigation it also allows you to set images for different filter values.
So you can upload pictures with the colors and use them.
It's not free, but for sure it's cheaper than coding it yourself.

---

<sub>I'm in no way associated with the extension provider. I just used the extension and liked it</sub>

Comment: can you tell me how to code myself....i would be grateful if you will tell me step by step plz becoz its very urgent

Comment: @PrinceKumar. Sorry, but I don't know how to code it. It's kind of a big task. If it's urgent I think you can spend 100$ on the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tonbo Color Picker. You can download it from [Tonbo Color Picker Download](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/tonbo-colorpicker.html)